# Test a launcher app icon on an iPhone

Tags: ios, icon

I need to test a launcher app icon on an iPhone. Is there any way to do that without having to install an entire app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an HTML page for this which refers to the icon.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png"/>
```

If you then open the web page and add the site to your home screen it will take `custom_icon.png` as your app icon.

For more detailed information have a look at [Apple's developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/configuringwebapplications/configuringwebapplications.html).

Comment: Great - thanks so much, cyphorious! That worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tools for testing icon design such as http://www.ikonica.me, it's much quicker than creating an HTML file, especially if you have to test multiple designs at once.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use http://testico.net. Nothing to download on your desktop, no app to install on your phone, free.